# php header, content type png doesn't work

Tags: php, gd

I am having hard time with php headers, i'm trying to create any kind of image in my browser without saving it in a file, but no matter what i do i can't get it working.

So for example if i use this basic example from php manual:

```
$im = imagecreate(100, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

It would set correct header and even output that icon which u get when image is not found.

Also i use `xampp` which have GD enabled, here is my `phpinfo` GD part:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.3
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.46
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

Is my code is wrong or do i need to configure something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not only create the image but also fill it some way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$im = imagecreate(100, 100) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, i've tried to look at it with firefox, and this is what i got: `The image “http://localhost/test/” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.`

Comment: Double checked it. :-/ Try the updated code (with `die` for initialization of image in case of failure) to ensure GD is working ok.

Comment: the problem was that i had empty space before <?php tag and this messed up my image :) anyways thatnks for the help

Answer (score 2):

PHP is probably outputting an error message, thus messing up the binary image data. For this reason I always disable `display_errors` and enable `log_errors` in the PHP configuration when working with image scripts; that way you can see any errors without screwing up the output. If you're sure there are no PHP errors in play, try dumping the full script output to a file (`ob_start();` at the beginning of the script, `file_put_contents("outfile", ob_get_clean());` at the end) and analyze that with a hex editor to see what's messing up the PNG.